MacOS split DNS not working as intended
I have a split DNS configuration setup by a VPN profile
$ scutil --dns

[...removed for conciseness, but basically the standard output of this command...]

resolver #2
  search domain[0] : my-domain.ch
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.11.41
  nameserver[1] : 192.168.11.41
  if_index : 24 (ipsec0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)

But when I do lookups for subdomains of my-domain.ch, it does not work
$ nslookup nas.my-domain.ch

Server:     172.20.10.1
Address:    172.20.10.1#53

** server can't find nas.my-domain.ch: NXDOMAIN

It seems to keep using the default resolver address (in this case the mac is connected to an iPhone connection share)
If I query the intended DNS server directly, it works
$ nslookup nas.my-domain.ch 192.168.11.41

Server:     192.168.11.41
Address:    192.168.11.41#53

Name:   nas.my-domain.ch
Address: 192.168.11.43

The same profile does work on iOS. I have macOS Sequoia 15.2 (24C101)
EDIT: nslookup was used as an example. Resolution doesn't work when using dscacheutil or simply ping. Neither does it work when using a web browser (Safari or Firefox, checked to be using system DNS)

Don't use nslookup (or host or dig) to test this, since they don't use the system resolver, and don't even emulate its lookup policies -- they all just send queries to whatever DNS server is listed first in /etc/resolver.conf, ignoring additional resolvers like this, the /etc/hosts file, etc.  Use dscacheutil -q host -a name nas.my-domain.ch (or just ping nas.my-domain.ch). See my answer here.

@GordonDavisson Unfortunately this does not yield any results. I tested with google.com to make sure it worked and it indeed did. I used nslookup as an example, but my main concern is browser not working (in this case I tested with both Firefox (checked that it was set to use system dns) and Safari).

Do you mean the dscacheutil command didn't resolve the address? Also, do you have anything like iCloud Private Relay or a VPN turned on?

@GordonDavisson dscacheutil. iCloud Private Relay is turned off, and this is a split DNS for a VPN subnet, so it's a "local" dns (in regards to the VPN subnet). I configured this VPN via an MDM profile, which works flawlessly on iOS. What I'm trying to achieve here is split DNS for the search domain my-domain.ch.

In that case, I'm out of ideas. Sorry...

@GordonDavisson No worries, thank you for your assistance !

Could you please post the exact output of dscacheutil for nas.my-domain.ch? If it provides a command line switch to be verbose, please include that. [ Note: I have no clue about Apple systems and don't have access to a MAC, but possibly could help because the MAC OS terminal doesn't differ too much from a Unix terminal. ]

@Binarus The output is empty and there is no verbose switch. Maybe I can provide you with the full scutil --dns command, which resembles resolvectl a lot.

@Noah Then I guess I can't help either. I have no clue of MAC OS, but thought that I might see something in the output because it's Unix-like somehow. I had asked because @GordonDavisson has recommended to use dscacheutil -q host -a name nas.my-domain.ch, but you didn't post the output of that command. Admitted, if the output is empty, you can't post it :-( But honestly I am asking myself why there is not an error message at least. I rarely encounter commands (especially in Unix-like environments) that fail silently without outputting anything.

@Noah Never having worked with MAC OS, I have no clue whether scutil or resolvectl would be appropriate to analyze the problem. According to @GordonDavisson, we must be cautious because some of the tools ignore split DNS.
